# Create data frame with factor variable levels based on maximum of numeric variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I've used aggregate to create a data frame close to what I need. However, I'm having issues getting exactly what I want.

Suppose the raw data is as follows:

```
data


 Order Item Price Quantity
     1    A    10        1 
     1    A    20        3 
     2    B    30        1 
     2    C    40        1 
     3    B    30        1 
     4    C    50        1 
     5    A    10        1 
     5    B    40        2
```

I now sum price and quantity based on item and order.

```
data.new <- aggregate(cbind(price, quantity) ~ Order + Item, sum, data = data)
data.new

╔═══════╦══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Order ║ Item ║ Price ║ Quantity ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ A    ║    30 ║        4 ║
║     2 ║ B    ║    30 ║        1 ║
║     2 ║ C    ║    40 ║        1 ║
║     3 ║ B    ║    30 ║        1 ║
║     4 ║ C    ║    50 ║        1 ║
║     5 ║ A    ║    10 ║        1 ║
║     5 ║ B    ║    40 ║        2 ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

This works nice for Order = 1, but I need each row to be a unique Order. So, I wish to **summarize Item by the maximum Price for each unique Order**. Item is just a high level factor to give some indication of what drove most of the sale price for the unique order. It should look as follows:

```
data.new <- ????
data.new

╔═══════╦══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Order ║ Item ║ Price ║ Quantity ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ A    ║    30 ║        4 ║
║     2 ║ C    ║    70 ║        2 ║
║     3 ║ B    ║    30 ║        1 ║
║     4 ║ C    ║    50 ║        1 ║
║     5 ║ B    ║    50 ║        3 ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: FYI - All that crazy formatting of your example data makes it nearly impossible for anyone to actually _use_, which sort of defeats the purpose. Even better then my edit would be to provide the output of `dput(data)`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to format a table for stackexchange and referenced this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables which led me to this http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's just that when you provide example data for R questions, it's most important to do so in a way that's easy for people to transfer to their own R session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option (among many, many options) using **plyr**:

```
ddply(data,.(Order),
      summarise,
      Item = unique(Item[which.max(Price)]),
      Price = sum(Price),
      Quantity = sum(Quantity))

  Order Item Price Quantity
1     1    A    30        4
2     2    C    70        2
3     3    B    30        1
4     4    C    50        1
5     5    B    50        3
```

This assumes that you won't have the max Price split between two different Items.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does what I was asking for.  For the case when the max price is split between two different items it chooses the item that is first in alphabetical order which is sufficient for my needs.